# how i can set icon application in ubuntu with elctron builder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, electron, package.json, electron-builder

* **Version**: ^10.6.1

* **Target**: linux

i'm ubuntu user & and i could not set icon for my app.
this is the error:

```
No native production dependencies
Packaging for linux x64 using electron 1.4.1 to dist/linux-unpacked
⚠️  Application icon is not set, default Electron icon will be used
Building AppImage for arch x64
```

and this is build section of  my package.jason:

```
"build": {

  "appId": "985654798458542",

  "mac": {

  "category": "crm"

},
"win": {

  "iconUrl": "logo.png"

},

"linux": {

  "iconUrl": "logo.png"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [electron-builder quick-setup](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#quick-setup-guide):

> Create a directory build in the root of the project and save a
>   background.png (macOS DMG background), icon.icns (macOS app icon) and
>   icon.ico (Windows app icon) into it.
>
> The Linux icon set will be generated automatically based on the macOS
>   icns file (or you can put them into the build/icons directory if you
>   want to specify them yourself. The filename must contain the size
>   (e.g. 32x32.png) of the icon).

You will have to specify your icon via the mac-options, even though it's not a build target in your case.